# Getting data from firebase cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have created a collection with

`db.collection("userCal/"+currentUserUID+"/activities").add({event})`
and now im trying to query all of this data from firebase but i dont think im doing it correctly.

it looks like this in firebase

[image]

and inside activities it looks like this:

[image]

I have this right not but its failing.

```
let doc = await fire
  .firestore()
  .collection('userCal')
  .doc(currentUserUID)
  .collection("activities")
  .get()

let dataObj = doc.data();
console.log(dataObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `get()` on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) to fetch multiple documents from that collection, it returns a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) unlike using `get()` on a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) that just returns a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) of a single document. So you'll have to run a loop on all documents present in the response as shown below:

```
const qSnap = await fire
  .firestore()
  .collection('userCal')
  .doc(currentUserUID)
  .collection("activities")
  .get()

const data = qSnap.docs.map(d => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }))
console.log(data);
```